# Coefficients in Laurent Expansion - Complex Analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, contour-integration, residue-calculus, laurent-series

***Exercise :***

*Let :*

$$\frac{\cos(πz)}{e^{iπz/2} + 1} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} a_nz^n$$

*the Laurent Expansion of the function :*

$$f(z) = \frac{\cos(πz)}{e^{iπz/2} + 1}$$

*in the ring : $D=\{ z \in \mathbb C : 2 < |z| < 6 \}$ with centre the point $z_c = 0$.*

*Using the Laurent Theorem and the Residue Theorem, calculate the coefficients $a_n$, $\forall n \leq 0$.*

***Attempt :***

$$e^{iπz/2} + 1 = 0 \Leftrightarrow e^{iπz/2} = -1 \Leftrightarrow e^{iπz/2} = e^{(2k+1)iπ} \Leftrightarrow z_k = 4k + 2, k\in \mathbb Z $$

So, we have the points : $\{z_0 =2, z_1 = 6, \dots\}.$ Only the point $z_0=2$ belongs inside the circle $|z| = r$  :  $2<r<6$.

From the Laurent Theorem we have :

$$a_n = \frac{1}{2πi} \oint_{|z|=r} \frac{g(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz$$

where $g(z)$ we have the function :

$$g(z) = \frac{\cos(πz)}{e^{iπz/2} + 1}$$

First of all, we have :

$$a_0 = \oint_{|z|=r} \frac{g(z)}{z} dz= \oint_{|z|=r} \frac{\cos(πz)}{z(e^{iπz/2} + 1)}dz $$

Because the points : $0,2$ are *simple poles* of the function $h(z)= \frac{\cos(πz)}{z(e^{iπz/2} + 1)}$, from the *Theorem of Residues* we have :

$$a_0 = Res(h,0) + Res(h,2)$$

After that, if $n \leq -1$ then $ -(n+1) \geq 0$.

So, we have :

$$a_n = \oint_{|z|=r} \frac{z^{-(n+1)}\cos(πz)}{e^{iπz/2} + 1}dz$$

We see that $0$ is a (???) point (I do not know its name in English), so in this case only the point $z=2$ is inside the circle $|z| = r$ and it is a simple pole. So, from the *Theorem of Residues*, for $n\leq -1$, we have :

$$a_n = Res\Bigg(\frac{z^{-(n+1)}\cos(πz)}{e^{iπz/2} + 1},2\Bigg) , \forall n \leq 0$$

I would like to ask if my approach and solution is correct. I'm not sure about the ring thingy. If it's not correct, please point out my mistakes and provide me with a thorough explanation.

Comment: I think you are saying (correctly) that $z=0$ is a *removable singularity* of the function $\frac{\cos(\pi z)}{z^{n+1}(e^{i\pi z/2}+1)}$ when $n\le0$.

Comment: Your approach and solution both look correct! but I'd like to point out that you can simplify the last expression. Hint: if $f(z)$ has a simple pole at $z=z_0$ and has residue $r$ there, and if $g(z)$ is analytic near $z=z_0$, then $f(z)g(z)$ also has a simple pole at $z=z_0$ with residue $g(z_0)r$.

Comment: @GregMartin Thanks a lot or taking the time to check my approach and solution mate ! I didn't know about the simplification of the last expression, so thanks for that ! I'll check it out as well and write it down to remember!

Comment: You're welcome :) Yes, the fact I mentioned in my comment is very helpful; it's also really beneficial to understand why it's true, and also why it's no longer true if (for example) $f(z)$ has a double pole at $z=z_0$.